# При считывании чисел из файла в массив некорректно воспринимается первое число

Tags: java, файлы, исключения

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(reader.readLine()));
         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(reader.readLine())))
    {
        while (br.ready()){
            String str = br.readLine();
            String[] dstr = str.split("\\s");

            for (String s : dstr){
                try {
                    int i = (int) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(s)); // NumberFormatException для первого числа в файле
                    bw.write(i + " ");
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }

        reader.close();
        br.close();
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Числа в файл записаны следующим образом:

> 3.1415 23.41 8.919402 542.214 12.5 52.51

Comment: Кодировка у файла случайно не UTF-8 с BOM? Или любая другая с BOM? Если нет выложите стек ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Ваш файл входных данных сохранён в кодировке UTF-8 с [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). `FileReader` открывает файлы в системной кодировке. Для Windows - это cp1251. Получается, что последовательность символов до первого пробела - "п?ї3.1415". Естественно, что класс Double не знает, как её преобразовать в число. Для исправления проблемы надо, во-первых, открыть файл в той кодировке, в которой он сохранён, а во-вторых, убрать метку BOM из считываемых данных:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(reader.readLine()), "UTF-8"));
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(reader.readLine()))) {
    while (br.ready()) {
        String str = br.readLine();
        String[] dstr = str.replace("\uFEFF", "").split("\\s");

        for (String s : dstr) {
            try {
                int i = (int) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(s));
                bw.write(i + " ");
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Или просто сохраните файл без BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Обрати внимание на этот свой код:

```
try {
       int i = (int) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(s)); // NumberFormatException для первого числа в файле
       bw.write(i + " ");
 }
```

Числа у тебя в файле в формате Double, а ты перевел в int!